# $f(y)\geq f(x)\rightarrow (y-x)\geq0$ in $\mathbb{R^2_+}$ if weakly increasing?

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Suppose we have a $f(x,y)=x^5y^2$ defined on $\mathbb{R^2_+}$.

Can we claim
$f(y)\geq f(x)\rightarrow (y-x)\geq0$ in $\mathbb{R^2_+}$ if weakly increasing?

See if the below argument is valid or not:

> (1) Suppose we have a $f(x,y)=x^5y^2$ defined on $\mathbb{R^2_+}$.
>   
>  (2) Suppose $f(y)\geq f(x)$ for some $y,x$ in the domain.
>   
>  (3) $Df=(5y^2x^4\quad 2x^5y)$, both partials non-negative on its domain.
>   
>  (4) The function is weakly increasing in both of its argument.
>   
>  (5) Then, $y-x\geq0$.
>   
>  Additionally, we can claim that $(y-x)Df(x)\geq0$.

Comment: Generally, bad to go from $x,y$ being a pair of real numbers to $x$ and $y$ both being a pair of real numbers.

Comment: Also, it's is not clear what you mean by "weakly increasing" here. What does $(u,v)\geq (w,z)$ mean?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, absolutely. So that was my confusion. If we are looking at $\mathbb{R^2_+}$, how does $y\geq x$ mean, because we have two components, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample:

Let's evaluate $f$ at two points:
$$f(1,1)=1$$

$$f\left(2^2,\frac{1}{2^5}\right)=1$$

Hence $$f(1,1) \geq f\left(2^2,\frac{1}{2^5}\right)$$ and $$f\left(2^2,\frac{1}{2^5}\right) \geq f(1,1).$$

If the claim is right, then we have

$$(1,1) \geq \left(2^2,\frac{1}{2^5}\right)$$ and $$\left(2^2,\frac{1}{2^5}\right) \geq (1,1).$$